# Save and retrieve an image file in LibGDX

Tags: java, android, libgdx

How to Save and retrieve an image file in LibGDX. I want to save an image file in local storage in AndroidApplication class and retrieve it in my Core project.

Comment: You mean loading an image from project assets in LibGDX?

Comment: No, I want to get image from external storage and save in local storage @Nanoc

Comment: Did you read the libgdx documentation on file management? It's pretty straight-forward.

Answer (score 3):

The file handling in Libgdx is well describe in the [libGDX wiki](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/File-handling).

In a nutshell: you are opening the file using FileHandle object that can be retrieved by calling one of

```
    Gdx.files.external("path.txt"); //files on SD card [Android]
    Gdx.files.absolute("path.txt"); //absolute path to file
    Gdx.files.internal("path.txt"); //asset directory
    Gdx.files.local("path.txt"); //local storage - only here you can write safely!
```

Then creating texture from file looks like

```
    Texture tex = new Texture( Gdx.files.internal("path.jpg") );
```

Then what you should do would be to get a file using **external()** to retrieve [FileHandle](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/files/FileHandle.html), then do whatever you want with it and just save it using **local()**. FileHandle has methods **readBytes()** and **writeBytes** that allows you to open/save data

```
    FileHandle from = Gdx.files.external("image.jpg");
    byte[] data = from.readBytes();

    ...

    FileHandle to = Gdx.files.local("image.jpg");
    to.writeBytes(data);
```

---

if you want to modify the image before saving it you should take a look at [Pixmap](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/Pixmap.html) and [PixmapIO](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/PixmapIO.html) classes

Answer (score 0):

I hope you dont want to store something on assets folder, because that cannot be done.

You can save it in the internal storage using basic java, take a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html#WriteInternalStorage)

Hope this helps.